# Python 3.x rounding half up

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I know that questions about rounding in python have been asked multiple times already, but the answers did not help me. I'm looking for a method that is rounding a float number half up and returns a float number. The method should also accept a parameter that defines the decimal place to round to. I wrote a method that implements this kind of rounding. However, I think it does not look elegant at all.

```
def round_half_up(number, dec_places):
    s = str(number)

    d = decimal.Decimal(s).quantize(
        decimal.Decimal(10) ** -dec_places,
        rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)

    return float(d)
```

I don't like it, that I have to convert float to a string (to avoid floating point inaccuracy) and then work with the *decimal* module. 
Do you have any better solutions?

Edit: As pointed out in the answers below, the solution to my problem is not that obvious as correct rounding requires correct representation of numbers in the first place and this is not the case with float. So I would expect that the following code

```
def round_half_up(number, dec_places):

    d = decimal.Decimal(number).quantize(
        decimal.Decimal(10) ** -dec_places,
        rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)

    return float(d)
```

(that differs from the code above just by the fact that the float number is directly converted into a decimal number and not to a string first) to return 2.18 when used like this: `round_half_up(2.175, 2)` But it doesn't because `Decimal(2.175)` will return `Decimal('2.17499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')`, the way the float number is represented by the computer.
Suprisingly, the first code returns 2.18 because the float number is converted to string first. It seems that the str() function conducts an implicit rounding to the number that was initially meant to be rounded. So there are two roundings taking place. Even though this is the result that I would expect, it is technically wrong.

Comment: @IcesHay I'm not sure if I get what you mean by rounding the number half up. Can you give us some examples?

Comment: @Kenivia What I mean by that is, that you round the relevant decimal place from 0-4 down and from 5-9 up: If rounding to 0 decimal places: 2.4 = 2; 2.5 = 3; 3.5 = 4 etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rounding is surprisingly hard to do *right*, because you have to handle floating-point calculations very carefully. If you are looking for an *elegant* solution (short, easy to understand), what you have like like a good starting point. To be correct, you should replace `decimal.Decimal(str(number))` with creating the decimal from the number itself, which will give you a decimal version of its exact representation:

```
d = Decimal(number).quantize(...)...
```

`Decimal(str(number))` effectively rounds *twice*, as formatting the float into the string representation performs its own rounding. This is because `str(float value)` won't try to print the full decimal representation of the float, it will only print enough digits to ensure that you get the same float back if you pass those exact digits to the `float` constructor.

If you want to retain correct rounding, but avoid depending on the big and complex `decimal` module, you can certainly do it, but you'll still need *some* way to implement the exact arithmetics needed for correct rounding. For example, you can use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html):

```
import fractions, math

def round_half_up(number, dec_places=0):
    sign = math.copysign(1, number)
    number_exact = abs(fractions.Fraction(number))
    shifted = number_exact * 10**dec_places
    shifted_trunc = int(shifted)
    if shifted - shifted_trunc >= fractions.Fraction(1, 2):
        result = (shifted_trunc + 1) / 10**dec_places
    else:
        result = shifted_trunc / 10**dec_places
    return sign * float(result)

assert round_half_up(1.49) == 1
assert round_half_up(1.5) == 2
assert round_half_up(1.51) == 2
assert round_half_up(2.49) == 2
assert round_half_up(2.5) == 3
assert round_half_up(2.51) == 3
```

Note that the only tricky part in the above code is the precise conversion of a floating-point to a fraction, and that can be off-loaded to the [`as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio) float method, which is what both decimals and fractions do internally. So if you really want to remove the dependency on `fractions`, you can reduce the fractional arithmetic to pure integer arithmetic; you stay within the same line count at the expense of some legibility:

```
def round_half_up(number, dec_places=0):
    sign = math.copysign(1, number)
    exact = abs(number).as_integer_ratio()
    shifted = (exact[0] * 10**dec_places), exact[1]
    shifted_trunc = shifted[0] // shifted[1]
    difference = (shifted[0] - shifted_trunc * shifted[1]), shifted[1]
    if difference[0] * 2 >= difference[1]:  # difference >= 1/2
        shifted_trunc += 1
    return sign * (shifted_trunc / 10**dec_places)
```

Note that testing these functions brings to spotlight the approximations performed when creating floating-point numbers. For example, `print(round_half_up(2.175, 2))` prints `2.17` because the decimal number `2.175` cannot be represented exactly in binary, so it is replaced by an approximation that happens to be slightly smaller than the 2.175 decimal. The function receives that value, finds it smaller than the actual fraction corresponding to the 2.175 decimal, and decides to round it **down**. This is not a quirk of the implementation; the behavior derives from properties of floating-point numbers and is also present in the `round` built-in of Python [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) and [2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round).

Comment: The problem with `d = Decimal(number).quantize(...)` is, that there is no exact representation of float numbers. So `Decimal(2.175)` will give you Decimal('2.17499999...') (and thus rounding will be incorrect) while `Decimal('2.175')` is Decimal('2.175'). That's why I'm converting to string first.

Comment: @IcesHay It is true that there is no exact representation of a number like 0.1 (i.e. the fraction 1/10) in binary because its denominator is not a power of 2. But once you have an actual Python float, the approximation has already happened, and the number you have in memory _does_ have an exact representation, it is provided by `as_integer_ratio()` (in case of 0.1, that would be 3602879701896397/36028797018963968). The `decimal.Decimal(float)` constructor uses that representation and the subsequent rounding will be correct and performed exactly.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I tested the function `round_half_up(2.175, 2)` and it returned 2.17 which is incorrect. Maybe there is something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @IcesHay That's exactly the thing, 2.175 is approximated when read as a float, into a number exactly representable as the fraction 2448832297382707/1125899906842624, which is slightly smaller than 2.175. (You can test this with `'%.20f' % 2.175` which evaluates to `'2.17499999999999982236'`.) For example, in Python 2.7, which uses half-up rounding, round(2.175) returns 2.17, and this kind of result is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) as a limitation of floating-point.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified a couple of things. I just want to point out, that I was looking for a solution that is working 100% correctly **in spite of floating point inaccuracy**. That's why I'm converting to string first, because it seems that this is representing the float value correctly in a string.

Comment: @IcesHay That's not how floating point works. Once a string is read into floating-point, the original number (which would distinguish "2.175" from "2.174999999999...") is irretrievably lost. Your question is about implementing the round-half-up of numbers, which is what this answer provides. It seems that your actual problem is something else entirely, because it now turns out that even Python 2 `round` (which does implement round-half-up) is also not good enough. Please edit the question to specify the actual use case - perhaps it would be satisfied by avoiding floats and using decimals.

Comment: Specifically, an answer that rounds the number that results from reading "2.175" to 2.18 would be incorrect because the actual float is smaller than 87/40 (the fraction corresponding to 2.175). If you are first converting to string and then rounding up, then you are actually doing **two** roundings, one implicit in conversion to the "2.175" and the other when decimally rounding that string to 2.18. Doing two roundings like that is not correct and has nothing to do with the distinction between banker's rounding and half-up.

Comment: I understand. If I want to round correctly I should make sure the numbers I want to round are represented correctly and therefore not use float. It makes no sense to round `float(2.175)` to 2.18 because 2.174999999... is just not going to be 2.18 using half-up rounding. I will take a closer look at this issue the next couple of days. After that I'll update my question (or accept your answer) and clean up this comment section.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't like it, that I have to convert float to a string (to avoid
>   floating point inaccuracy) and then work with the decimal module. Do
>   you have any better solutions?

Yes; use `Decimal` to represent your numbers throughout your whole program, if you need to represent numbers such as 2.675 exactly and have them round to 2.68 instead of 2.67.

There is no other way. The floating point number which is shown on your screen as 2.675 is **not** the real number 2.675; in fact, it is very slightly less than 2.675, which is why it gets rounded down to 2.67:

```py
>>> 2.675 - 2
0.6749999999999998
```

It only shows in string form as `'2.675'` because that happens to be the shortest string such that `float(s) == 2.6749999999999998`. Note that this longer representation (with lots of 9s) isn't exact either.

However you write your rounding function, it is not possible for `my_round(2.675, 2)` to round up to `2.68` and also for `my_round(2 + 0.6749999999999998, 2)` to round down to `2.67`; because the inputs are actually the same floating point number.

So if your number 2.675 ever gets converted to a float and back again, you have already lost the information about whether it should round up or down. The solution is not to make it float in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

After trying for a very long time to produce an elegant one-line function, I ended up getting something that is comparable to a dictionary in size.

I would say the simplest way to do this is just to

```
def round_half_up(inp,dec_places):
    return round(inp+0.0000001,dec_places)
```

i would acknowledge that this is not accurate in every cases, but should work if you just want a simple quick workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your solution may be simple, but it is an easy way out, and not very practical. Just to clarify once again: I'm looking for a solution, that is rounding float values correctly "half up" to any decimal place. I'm curious if anybody else had a similar problem and has an elegant and effective solution to this.

Comment: This solution is incorrect; for example, `round_half_up(1.499999999, 0)` returns 2.0 instead of 1.0.

Comment: @user4815162342 it does not as round normally rounds 1.5 down, which is why op asked this question in the first place

Comment: @user4815162342 but yes, it's not accurate in those cases. but if you just want 1.5 to be rounded down I think this is a nice quick workaround. Great answer from your part btw :)

Comment: Thanks. If you'd asked me yesterday, I would have said that rounding 1.499999999 to 2.0 was incorrect both generally, and for the OP in particular. But after the latest round of discussion with the OP in the comments to my answer, I am no longer sure, and am beginning to think that the question is not answerable in its current form. In that light, I am rescinding my downvote.